# why mx controls in flex not supporting japanese strings?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

is not displaying japanese characters but only displaying english characters ? Why mx controls not supporting japanese strings in flex ?

Japanese characters are not displaying in button instead of that blank or white space appearing on my label

Comment: Are you using a custom font? Make sure that your font is supporting japanese characters - it must support unicode characters. And if you are embedding your font check  that there are no unicodeRange settings (that would restrict which characters to import).

Comment: I dont use Flex but if possilbe to set a font then try Arial. You might have to embed the font also. I can only confirm that a basic AS3 textfield could display Japanese text (dunno about this "mx controls" stuff).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must have added your locale specific properties file under your project structure(example: ProjectName>src>**locale>ja_JP>japanese.properties**)

Please check you added correct compiler option?
*-locale en_US ja_JP –source-path ./locale/{locale}*

Follow the bellow steps to set the option:
1. Right-click your project and select Properties.
2. Select Flex Compiler on the left, and add the following to the Additional Compiler Arguments settings

Setting this additional locales in the compiler arguments in Flash Builder is mandatory.

Let me know if this fix your problem.

If you find it useful then please mark as answered.